# Selecting with conditions from a dataframe using Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to Scala and am having a hard time working with a simple dataset in Spark. I want to be able to review the following dataset ordering by EventType and crow, but can't get it to do it by Descending value. I also want to read out just one eventType at a time.

when I try

```
dataset.orderBy("eventType")
```

It works, but if I add a '.desc' it doesn't work.

```
scala> setB.orderBy("eventType").desc
<console>:32: error: value desc is not a member of 
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
   setB.orderBy("eventType").desc
```

or

```
scala> dataset.orderBy("eventType".desc)
<console>:32: error: value desc is not a member of String
   dataset.orderBy("eventType".desc)
```

I also am trying to use Filter, but it doesn't like anything I try either.
something like:
    dataset.filter("eventType"="agg%")

Sample dataset:

```
+----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-------------+----------------+----+
|deadletterbucket|split                                                                               |eventType                          |clientVersion|dDeviceSurrogate|crow|
+----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-------------+----------------+----+
|event_failure   |instance type (null) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: ["object"])|aggregate_event.app_launches       |4.3.0.108    |1               |3   |
|event_failure   |instance type (null) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: ["object"])|aggregate_event.app_launches       |5.3.0.10     |1               |11  |
|event_failure   |instance type (null) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: ["object"])|aggregate_event.app_launches       |5.9.1.10     |3               |11  |
|event_failure   |instance type (null) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: ["object"])|aggregate_event.app_launches       |5.7.0.1      |3               |15  |
|event_failure   |instance type (null) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: ["object"])|aggregate_event.app_launches       |5.5.0.5      |6               |16  |
|event_failure   |instance type (null) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: ["object"])|aggregate_event.app_launches       |4.0.0.62     |7               |26  |
|event_failure   |instance type (null) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: ["object"])|aggregate_event.app_launches       |4.6.4.6      |9               |31  |
|event_failure   |instance type (null) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: ["object"])|aggregate_event.app_network_traffic|7.12.0.113   |1               |1   |
|event_failure   |instance type (null) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: ["object"])|aggregate_event.app_network_traffic|6.3.2.15     |1               |2   |
|event_failure   |instance type (null) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: ["object"])|aggregate_event.app_network_traffic|5.1.2.10     |1               |3   |
```

Ideally, I am trying to get something like the following to work

```
dataset.orderBy("crow").desc.filter("eventType"="%app_launches").show(3,false)


|event_failure   |instance type (null) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: ["object"])|aggregate_event.app_launches       |5.5.0.5      |6               |31  |
|event_failure   |instance type (null) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: ["object"])|aggregate_event.app_launches       |4.0.0.62     |7               |26  |
|event_failure   |instance type (null) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: ["object"])|aggregate_event.app_launches       |4.6.4.6      |9               |16  |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost have the correct solution, just missing syntax details. The correct syntax with Spark(scala) is as below,

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

 dataset.orderBy(desc("crow")).filter($"eventType".contains("app_launches")).show(3, false)
```

You can access the column using either `$` or `col` you can find more information here (https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html)

I can also recommend going through this tutorial from spark homepage, its quite helpful! https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a `String` to identify the column you wish to order by. This is a convenience method, but if you want more control you need to pass a `Column` argument instead. Spark offers several idiomatic ways of retrieving this object from the dataset:

`dataset.orderBy($"crow".desc)...`

`dataset.orderBy(col("crow").desc)...`

`dataset.orderBy('crow.desc)...`

`dataset.orderBy(dataset("crow").desc)...`

See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@sort(sortExprs:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]